# Squid3 http Issue

Tags: debian, squid

I got Squid3 running on my MyBookLive (Debian Squeeze).
I succesfully installed Squid3 but **it stops serving http requests after some time, https does still work.**
If I check the access.log I see something like this multiple times:

```
1395679077.078   5250 10.0.0.2 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://10.0.0.2:3128/space - DIRECT/10.0.0.2 -
1395679077.080   5250 10.0.0.2 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://10.0.0.2:3128/space - DIRECT/10.0.0.2 -
1395679077.083   5250 10.0.0.2 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://10.0.0.2:3128/space - DIRECT/10.0.0.2 -
1395679077.083   5247 10.0.0.2 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://10.0.0.2:3128/space - DIRECT/10.0.0.2 -
1395679077.084   5245 10.0.0.2 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://10.0.0.2:3128/space - DIRECT/10.0.0.2 -
1395679077.085   5243 10.0.0.2 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://10.0.0.2:3128/space - DIRECT/10.0.0.2 -
```

And if I just keep refreshing, nothing gets added to the log so it makes me believe that Squid3 is not receiving anything.

Furthermore, I am using the default Squid3 config with the following edits:

```
http_port 3128 transparent
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/24
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
```

Here is the complete config file in a paste: http://pastebin.com/5pvR7dYY

EDIT

cache.log:

```
2014/03/24 17:37:56| IpIntercept.cc(137) NetfilterInterception:  NF getsockopt(SO_ORIGINAL_DST) failed on FD 1912: (92) Protocol not available
2014/03/24 17:37:56| WARNING: Forwarding loop detected for:
GET /space HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.2:3128
Via: 1.0 server01 (squid/3.1.6), 1.1 server01 (squid/3.1.6), 1.1 server01 (squid/3.1.6), 1.1 server01 (squid/3.1.6), 1.1 server01 (squid/3.1.6), 1.1 server01 (sq$
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.2, 10.0$
Cache-Control: max-age=259200
Connection: keep-alive
```

iptables in my dd-wrt router:

```
PROXY_IP=10.0.0.2
PROXY_PORT=3128
LAN_IP=`nvram get lan_ipaddr`
LAN_NET=$LAN_IP/`nvram get lan_netmask`

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s ! $PROXY_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $PROXY_IP:$PROXY_PORT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp -j SNAT --to $LAN_IP
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp --dport $PROXY_PORT -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: looks like you have a forwarding loop on 10.0.0.2 , see http://www.comfsm.fm/computing/squid/FAQ-11.html#ss11.31

Comment: @LinuxDevOps I don't quite understand how, I only have one cache and that's on 10.0.0.2. I also have the visible_hostname directive set in the conf.

Comment: The log files are very telling about the loop. It may come from the iptables rules which are confusing with just one interface br0; you may want to create a new (alias/dummy) interface to distinguish incoming from outgoing traffic. To debug the current iptables rules and traffic flow you can use tcpdump or iptables' LOG facility.

Comment: @LinuxDevOps I wouldn't know where to start honestly, before, when I had Squid3 on my HP Thin Client running Ubuntu 10.04, it worked good and without forwarding loops.

Comment: @LinuxDevOps Ah I see where your going, I got the iptables code from dd-wrt forums and it was confirmed to be working by a poster there. So how can this be changed then? Gosh I wish I knew iptables more..I am just not much of a sysadmin lol.

Comment: I used a ready-to-go config and it started working, somehow the forward loop error is gone.
Why and how? http://pastebin.com/knApFSnN

Comment: I deleted my comment while you were answering because upon more thought I was wrong regarding iptables loop, seems there was an issue with Squid's config

Comment: @LinuxDevOps actually it's not over yet, when reconfiguring/starting/stopping Squid3 manually it goes back into the endless forwarding loops. When I restart the device it goes back to normal. I found that out by running squid3 -k reconfigure for a blacklist. I then rebooted and I could access the internet again. Edit: I tried to reproduce it but it's not doing it again. This is being spammed in the cache.log: 
2014/03/24 22:56:28| IpIntercept.cc(137) NetfilterInterception:  NF getsockopt(SO_ORIGINAL_DST) failed on FD 41: (92) Protocol not available
 maybe some kind of buffer overflow?